# Is it possible to render PDF (fPDF) via a javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, fpdf

So, I'm passing some values via jQuery to the server, which generates PDF garble. It goes something like this:

```
$.post('/admin/printBatch',
data, // Some vars and such
function(data){
    if(data) {

        var batch =  window.open('','Batch Print','width=600,height=600,location=_newtab');
        var html = data; // Perhaps some header info here?!
        batch.document.open();
        batch.document.write(html);
        batch.document.close();

        $( this ).dialog( "close" ); // jQuery UI
    } else {
        alert("Something went wrong, dawg.");
    }
    return false;
});
```

The output file looks roughly like so:

```
$pdf->AddPage(null, null, 'A PDF Page');
//....
$pdf->Output('', 'I'); // 'I' sends the file inline to the browser (http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)
```

What gets rendered to the browser window:

```
%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream ...
```

I'm missing something major, I just know it... thoughts?

Thanks, guys.

Comment: Hello LaRosee, Have you got any solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of things, the PDF is reasonably well formed. As such, I suspect you simply need to set the appropriate content header when you're outputting the PDF via PHP using the [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

N.B.: This *must* be the first output from the PHP - it won't work if there's preceding HTML, blank space, etc.

In an ideal world, you'd also set the content length, etc. via...

```
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($pathToYourPDF));
```

...or...

```
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($pdfData));
```

...if you're generating the PDF programmatically.

**UPDATE**

To clarify, **I suspect you'll need to change your window.open to read the above directly from a PHP served URL** for the above to work. (Not quite sure why you're not just doing this in the first place, but I guess there's a good reason.)

Comment: Would this really work if he's storing it in a string? I'd imagine all meta data is lost...

Comment: @Blindy - To be honest, I've sort of assumed he'll need to change the window.open to point directly at a PHP that does the above, as I don't believe such things can't be set via JavaScript. Hmm... should really update my answer to say this. :-)

Comment: Hi guys. So, the FPDF class sets the headers just before dumping the buffer: if(php_sapi_name()!='cli')
{
 //We send to a browser
 header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
 if(headers_sent())
 $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');
 header('Content-Length: '.strlen($this->buffer));
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'"');
 header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
 header('Pragma: public');
 ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');
}
echo $this->buffer;

Comment: @Middaparka - The reason I'm not pointing the window.open to a URL is because I'm generating the PDF and passing it back via the jQuery ajax callback... which is probably something I"ll have to abandon. I'm using jQuery to .foreach() on various inputs and then using those values to generate the PDF and (in theory) pass the generated buffer back to the browser and THEN open a new window via the JS.

Comment: I'm going to give Middaparka the credit because I ended up forgoing the concept of passing the PDF buffer *back* from the ajax call and am making a more direct call to the "PHP served URL."

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this for my application and my conclusion is that you must use an iframe (where show_pdf returns "$pdf->Output('', 'I');"):

```
$.ajax({
 url: "http://www.somesite.com/documents/generatePDF",
 success: function(){
  $('#theDocument').html('<iframe id="some_id" class="some_pdf" style="display:none" src="http://www.somesite.com/documents/show_pdf" width="100%" height="450" scrollbar="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" align="middle" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="width:100%; border:0;  height:450px; overflow:auto;"></iframe>');
 }
});
$('#dialog-document').dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather set `URL` for the popup window, pointing to the php script that outputs PDF.

If you absolutely have to do it this way, data-uri might help:

```
var batch =  window.open(
                    'data:application/pdf,'+encodeURIComponent(data),
                    'Batch Print',
                    'width=600,height=600,location=_newtab'
             );
```

but I have not tested it, and even if it works in normal browsers, in IE it is sure to fail.

Comment: Actually it would work in IE, but anything over a few KB would be insanely slow. I once pasted a 200kb image as data in chrome and it took like half a minute to display it... It's because of the way they allocate their addresses since they don't expect it to grow too much.

Comment: It appears that URI encoding is not sufficient, data should be base64 encoded and will work with `'data:application/pdf;base64,'+data`;

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Change

```
$pdf->Output('', 'I');
```

for

```
$return = $pdf->Output('name.pdf', 'S');
$return = base64_encode();
$return = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'.$return;
echo json_encode($return);
```

now, you should, in your javascript file, get the return and open a new window

```
success: function( data ) {
    var pdf = JSON.parse(data);
    window.open(pdf);
}
```

It will open a new tab on your browser with the pdf.